# Why bootstrap class center-block with img-responsive is not positioning image at center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align an image at center using bootstrap classes img-responsive and center-block. But somehow the image doesn't get aligned at center horizontally when tested from browser (IE and chrome).

Strange that same html when tried using fiddle aligns it at center.

Can you please help me find what can I correct in code so the image is centered on the page horizontally?

Fiddle is at [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/46y33ytz/1/)

Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <img src="http://www.wallpapersonly.net/wallpapers/monocles-lens-testing-1280x800.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, it seems to be working on JSFiddle; probably because the preview doesn't get to be interpreted as a large screen.

You are using a `col-md-8` as parent of the image, so the area considered by the image is reduced and aligned to the left, therefore, it doesn't look centered to the whole screen;

To solve it, you can either remove the `col-md-8` class or add `col-md-offset-2` to it;

You can check out more about grids at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the link to more information on grid. adding offset worked for me and did what I was looking for.